# Does Flight Following automatically include permission to fly through class C or D airspace?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, airspace, class-c-airspace

The situation is as following - I requested flight following at approach, got a squawk and instructed to maintain VFR with heading and altitude at my discretion. My route is through class D and class C airspace for the altitude I chose. The question is - should I establish additional communications or report to the approach controller about flying through the class C and D airspace, or I am already permitted to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Lets back up a minute and discuss what is required to enter C and D airspace.

For C and D airspace you must establish 2 way radio communications with tower or approach controller. Let's first discuss how this works if you are not taking Flight Following. As you approach Class C airspace you hail them and wait for a response, for example,

> You: "Allentown Approach Piper 1234J @ 3000 en route to Queen City Municipal"
>
> Controller: "1234J Squawk 1-3-5-2 and Ident"

Since the controller responded with your tail number you may enter the Charlie airspace (Delta has the same requirements).

Now when you are under Flight Following, ATC will coordinate a handoff to the Approach or Tower for the airspace you are about to enter, or ATC will say "radar services terminated," and you must contact the controller/tower yourself before entering.

You **SHOULD NOT** change frequencies until you are told to do so, since ATC may be trying to give you a traffic advisory. You can however tune your second radio (if you have one) to the approach/tower you are approaching, and begin to monitor traffic.

Comment: To amplify a point that is screwed up frequently where I fly: If flight following drops you or you're booted out of the IFR system (i.e. "If the controller says `Radar services terminated`") *you are no longer in two-way radio communication with ATC* and are not authorized to enter Class C and D airspace. (You're also not authorized to enter Class B airspace in this situation, obviously.) You must establish two-way communication with the controlling authority for that airspace on your own prior to entry.

Comment: Often the controller you're talking to will notify the tower or appch controller and approve a frequency change. Wonderful! But **you** have not yet established two-way comms with the *right* ATC and therefore have not met that requirement. Upon being approved for a freq change, attempt to contact the controller and if that fails (e.g. he's busy), _avoid_ the airspace until two-way comm is established. If flying *through* controlled airspace the same applies; request a handoff from the controller you're talking to if he hasn't volunteered one, and don't enter until comms are established.

Comment: @voretaq7 your point about "Radar Services Terminated" is not quite true. To enter Class C, you must be in 2-way radio contact with the *controlling authority*. You can't call up, say, New York Center and then enter a Class C controlled by NY Approach. Once center hears your altitude & position, they will tell you "N69VT, contact approach on ..."  So even though you hear your numbers, that is not 2-way radio communications sufficient to enter the Class C because NY Center is not the controlling authority. It is the 2d phrase "Frequency change approved" that terminates your 2-way radio contact.

Comment: (con't)  The phraseology is "N69VT, Radar services terminated, squawk VFR, frequency change approved."  Perhaps your TRACON abbreviates it to simply "Radar services terminated"?

Comment: @hemp -- no, you do NOT need to be in 2-way contact with the new controller before entering Class C or D. the actual handoff has already been accomplished in the radar system, and the receiving controller has already accepted the handoff. that is sufficient.  I know these last comments sound like they are in contradiction, but you have to think about the way the entire system works. If the receiving controller cannot accept the handoff from the sending controller, the sending controller will drop you, and you are not allowed to enter.

Comment: @voretaq7 -- the controller may still want you in the Charlie even if he can't work you on radar (lets say the radar at his TRACON died while you were getting ready to shoot an approach -- kicking you out of the Charlie makes far less sense than simply reverting back to non-radar procedures).

Comment: @rbp -- That isn't guaranteed. **if** the controller you are talking to has handed you off then you're fine. But flight following is *not* the same as IFR, it's a secondary service, and a busy controller may not hand you off before you enter someone else's airspace as they're not required to. If that happens and you enter the airspace anyway, you are violating and you'll likely get a very unpleasant instruction from that controller to call and explain yourself. If I haven't been given a frequency change, I never assume I'm clear to enter. Usually I'll just call and request the change.

Comment: @hemp if the controller can't hand you off, he has to tell you, and then yes, you have to call the next controller before entering. what he can't do is not hand you off and not tell you.

Comment: @rbp -- I'll agree it is _bad controlling technique_ to not notify me of impending encroachment on Class D, C, or B airspace. But ultimately as a pilot I cannot make any assumptions about a controller's use of good controlling technique when he or she is providing me with a secondary service. Unless someone can point to a very clear JO that states that it is the controller's responsibility, I will continue to assume it is mine.

Comment: 7−6−11. TERMINATION OF SERVICE
Basic radar services should be provided to the extent
possible, workload permitting. **Terminate radar
service to aircraft landing at airports other than those
where sequencing service is provided *at a sufficient
distance from the airport to permit the pilot to change
to the appropriate frequency*** for traffic and airport
information (https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf)

Comment: also read 7−6−8. CONTROL TRANSFER. its too chopped up to quote here in a comment. Taken together, the controller is responsible for either telling you to contact the next controller or telling you he cannot.

Answer (score 8):

As per [JO 7110.65 **ATC**](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap2_section_1.html), Section 2-1-16 SURFACE AREAS, when you are in contact with ATC, you do not need to specifically ask for authorization to enter a towered service area:

> **b.** Coordinate with the appropriate control tower for transit authorization when you are providing radar traffic advisory service to
> an aircraft that will enter another facility's airspace.
>
> ***NOTE-***
> *The pilot is not expected to obtain his/her own authorization through each area when in contact with a radar facility.*

Comment: Nice find. Wonder if it's anywhere on the pilot side of regs.

Comment: Very nice find. However, I would caution that "not expected to" is not the same as "not required to". As the pilot, you are still responsible for following the regs, and VFR Flight Following is different than being under IFR control. Flight Following is workload-permitted for the controller, and VFR traffic is lower-priority than IFR. As the pilot, if your route goes through Class C and you haven't been given permission to enter, I'd ask before I got there and not enter if you still haven't received clearance.

Comment: there is no such thing as "reciev[ing] clearance" through Class C.  If you are talking to ATC, and they are communicating your tail number, and you have not be told to stay out, then you have permission to enter. You don't need to be given explicit permission.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on my part. No you don't need permission to enter C. B, yes, but C No. C I would still ping the controller before I got there. B I would ping the controller and stay out until cleared through.   After making a point of what you DON'T have to do, I kinda switched over to a "what WOULD I do" view.

Comment: Does this apply to VFR, IFR, or both?

Comment: IFR you are in positive control for the clearance you received so a second clearance isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already in radio contact with the ATC agency that controls the Charlie airspace (aka Approach), you are already allowed to enter it.

(If Approach doesn't want you in their Charlie, they'll say so: "N12345, remain outside the Charlie".)

Comment: To nitpick a bit, you don't actually need permission to enter the Class C airspace, just establish two-way communication. The controller has no say over what you do outside of his airspace. He can tell you "Don't enter", but you don't have to comply. You'd be foolish, not to, but you can enter anyway without violating any rules. However, once inside the Class C, if he says "Get out!" you have to follow his instruction. Class B is different. It requires permission to enter.

Comment: And to add irony to my nitpick, if you call the controller with your call sign, and he responds back with "N12345, remain outside the Charlie.", he has just established two-way communication with you and you are cleared to enter. Again, not wise, but you won't have violated any regs if you enter. Just angered ATC.

Comment: @shawn both of those are wrong. 91.123 (b) Except in an emergency, **no person may operate an aircraft contrary to an ATC instruction in an area in which air traffic control is exercised.**

Comment: @rbp You are correct. Except outside of a Class C, the controlling authority has no control over the pilot. I said it was kind of a nitpick, but all you need to enter Class C is two-way comms. You don't need permission. That falls under the last part of your statement "....in an area in which air traffic control is exercised." However, once you enter the Class C, you are obligated to follow the controller's instructions. 

Again, it would be unwise to pull that, but not a reg violation.

Comment: Air traffic control is exercised in all airspace classes except G, and also in towered class g airports.

Comment: Class E is primarily intended to separate IFR from VFR. A VFR pilot typically isn't under the control of ATC and isn't even required to have a radio in E. The only requirement for E is weather. Regardless, you don't need permission to enter C, just two-way comms. And a controller only has authority over you if you are in his airspace. Again, not wise to ignore ATC, but not illegal in this case.

Comment: @Shawn You are completely mistaken in all of the comments on this thread. 1. If you are given an instruction by ATC you must comply. So if you are told to stay out, you must stay out. 2. You can’t enter C or D airspace without establishing communication. Read the examples in the  AIM to clear up your confusion. 3. In Class E airspace  ATC keeps IFR traffic separate from other IFR traffic. If the conditions are VFR everyone is responsible for see-and-avoid.

Comment: @JScarry Good post necromancy, but please review my comments. There is no confusion. From a regulation standpoint, the Class C controller has NO authority over you until you are within the Class C airspace. You do not need permission to enter, just 2-way comms, as described above. Therefore, you CAN enter. But if he then tells you to leave, you have to follow his instructions. It's not a good idea to ignore ATC, but a pilot has broken no regs outside of the Class C. Feel free to ask the FAA. My point was, don't just take everything at face value. Actually _understand_ the regs you follow.

Comment: Now if those regs have changed over the last 15 years, please point me to that change. When I was teaching, that was how ATC control authority was always defined. ATC can't control you outside of their airspace, and they probably aren't likely to even try, since they usually understand their limitations also. If they need you to do something that will affect their airspace, they'll likely request the change be made by whoever's airspace you're in.

Comment: You may not think you are confused, but you are wrongity wrong wrong wrong. You might want to read the comments on the accepted answer. If you are talking to ATC, they have authority over you. I take §91.123   Compliance with ATC clearances and instructions. literally.
(a) When an ATC clearance has been obtained, no pilot in command may deviate from that clearance unless an amended clearance is obtained, an emergency exists, or the deviation is in response to a traffic alert and collision avoidance system resolution advisory. .

Comment: I ran across the Karas letter and thought it might be interesting to anyone following this thread, https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/pol_adjudication/agc200/interpretations/data/interps/2013/karas%20-%20%282013%29%20legal%20interpretation.pdf
"A pilot flying VFR in Class E airspace, which is controlled airspace, is not required to communicate with ATC; however, if a pilot is communicating with ATC and ATC issues an instruction, the pilot must comply with that instruction."